# LinqToSql InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, enums

Ok, so here's an enum, right?

```
    public enum BrandSafe : short
    {

        Yes = 1,
        No = -1,
        Unknown = 0

    }
```

Underlying datatype of short, OK, so far so good.

Here is a table:

[image]

Now, here is a DTO class:

```
public class VurlRow
{

    public long VurlRMXID { get; set; }
    public string VurlString { get; set; }
    public Enums.BrandSafe BrandSafe  { get; set; }


}
```

Finally, here is a linq method:

```
        List<VurlRow> vurls = (from vurl in m_Context.Vurls
                     select new VurlRow()
                                {
                                    BrandSafe = (Enums.BrandSafe)vurl.BrandSafe,
                                    VurlRMXID = vurl.VurlRMXID,
                                    VurlString = vurl.VurlString

                                }).ToList();
```

I've also tried (Enums.BrandSafe)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Enums.BrandSafe), vurl.BrandSafe) to produce the Enum. When I remove the line BrandSafe = (Enums.BrandSafe)vurl.BrandSafe, the call works, but with the line I get a InvalidCast exception.

"Specified cast is not valid."

Seems like it should be totally valid to me, but what do I know, not enough about enums and linq apparently, can anyone here help?

Comment: Try `(Enums.BrandSafe)(short)vurl.BrandSafe`

Comment: Can you provide a whole exception message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BrandSafe` is `tinyint` in the database; `tinyint` maps to `byte`, not `short`. That's the problem. Make it:

```
public enum BrandSafe : byte
{
    Yes = 1,
    No = -1, // <====== see below
    Unknown = 0
}
```

(`short` would map to `smallint`)

However!!!! Note that `-1` is not really a legal value for **either** of `byte`/`tinyint` - it will be 255 or an `OverflowException` in .NET (depending on whether it is a checked or unchecked context), and an arithmetic-overflow (error 220) at the database.

I do, however, wonder whether `bool?` (in C#) and `bit null` (TSQL) would be a better match.

Comment: Of course! Duh! I had changed it in the DBML but I guess I forgot to change the table. Thanks for the help, and also for making me feel like an idiot :)

Comment: @cerhart see also the last line I added

Comment: Right, I had made it a tiny int, but then I decided I wanted to use -1 as a value, I then changed the DBML to short, but forgot to set the table value to small int. Then I just refused to look at the table for the answer. Selective blindness.

Comment: @cerhart not a problem; I'm just grateful that you included all the right information to spot it!

Comment: I'm not a fan of nulls in the database, maybe because I'm lazy, but it  just seems to add more complexity, plus this way I can very explicit in the code using the enum i.e., Enum.BrandSafe.Unknown is very clear where a null could mean unknown, or it could mean non-applicability. Either way could work great of course, this way just suits me.